# Adding shaded areas onto a normal distribution for standard deviation and mean with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to add a "line" showing where the mean is to my code, and then shade in the area to the left and right of that line by one standard deviation.

What I have so far is the normal curve and the histogram. I am having trouble figuring out how to use fill_between properly.

The working code for normal dist and hist are below, but I'd like shading added.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\Work\my_data.csv')
df = df.dropna()

instructor_scores = df['Score Field']
sigma = instructor_scores.std()
mu = instructor_scores.mean()

fit = norm.pdf(instructor_scores, mu, sigma)

plt.plot(instructor_scores, fit, '-0')
plt.hist(instructor_scores, density=True)

plt.show()
```

I think fill_between is the right way to go, but I'm too new to know for sure. If I *were* to use that, how would it look? I've seen a couple of answers here re: fill_between, but I don't think I fully understand how to use it and the answers I saw were too advanced for what I'm looking for. When I plot I end up with a blue bar on top of my graph. I don't know the arguments to add to get even a basic fill_between onto my plot.

Comment: You didn't tell what you do not understand about other solutions; so the answer here would be the same as in other solutions.

Comment: Thanks, added a bit to try to explain how lost I am

Comment: Ok, but even if you don't understand it, why not copy the code and run it, then adapt it step by step to your data? The arguments to `fill_between` don't change.

Comment: Thanks, your advice actually helped me approach it from a different direction for some reason and I figured it out. Can you re-open so that I can submit an answer for my specific question?